# In Java is there a name for the object the method is called on?

Tags: java, objective-c

When I explain code, I often have to write "the object that the method is called on". E.g.

> The `contains()` method simply checks if the input substring is present in **the string you call the `contains()` on**.

In Objective-c I'd write

> The `contains()` method simply checks if the input substring is present in **receiver** (string).

Which makes sense as Objective-c uses message passing and a message has a sender and a receiver.

The lack of this expression for Java terminology makes descriptions very complicated when the object in question cannot be named explicitly. Does there exist a standard name for *the object that the method is called on*?

**VERDICT**: **receiver** seems to express the relationship the best.

Comment: Maybe `invoking` object. In javadoc, you can refer to the `calling` object as `this`.

Comment: `invoking object`, `calling object`, `given string`, `subject`... I'm not aware of standard terminology so you should be free to choose whatever sounds best in the given situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what having a reference to the calling object does. This isn't very OO.

If you intend to call a method in the object that's calling, then it would have to implement some interface. You can't have methods only accessible to be called by objects implementing some interface.

Comment: @Cruncher You've misunderstood. The question is about terminology. (You always have a reference to the calling object, `this`)

Comment: Why not stick with _receiver_? The abstraction of passing messages still seems like a decent working model for Java's method invocation.

Comment: if "this" is the correct answer then I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Sotirios yes, I realized that now

Comment: @Cruncher, as I understand it, the question is about calls like `foo.bar()`, and how to call the 'foo' object in this context.

Comment: I think receiver is fine. "Message passing" as implemented in Objective-C isn't true message passing, in the original sense of the term; it's more akin to Java's method invocation anyway, so co-opting the term doesn't seem like much of a stretch.

Comment: @mipadi - But the terminology of Objective-C is all screwed up.  It's a very poor model to follow.

Comment: @HotLicks: Aside from referring to it as "message passing" (which comes from Smalltalk, which *does* have its roots in true message passing OO systems), what terminology is screwed up?

Comment: Well, for starters, is it "class" or "interface"?

Comment: I will concede that for all Java calls that are expressed using the notation `[objectRef methodName]` the term "receiver" is OK.

Comment: @HotLicks: `[objectRef methodName]` vs `objectRef.methodName()` is just syntax.  Semantically they are both requesting `objectRef` to invoke the behavior associated with `methodName`.  This can result in entirely different outcomes depending on who receives the request, i.e, the current value of the receiver `objectRef`, and that receiver's implementation of `methodName`.

Comment: Actually, objectRef is not invoking the behavior.  The caller is invoking the behavior, and the invoked object (quite passively) simply routes to a specific implementation to perform that behavior.

Comment: @HotLicks: You have an odd view of "passive". As the owner of both the data and the method implementation, it is the sole prerogative of `objectRef` as to what the response will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called the "receiver". See [Terminology](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/softeng/object-oriented.html).

Comment: Why isn't it widely used?

Comment: I read the linked article, but I've never seen 'receiver' used in that fashion in java documentation.

Comment: "Receiver" is common in OO languages that speak of "sending messages" vs "calling".  I can't say that I've ever seen the term used in Java documentation.  (I've always thought the "sending" terminology was pretty flaky, since it goes back to some early OO languages such as Smalltalk that did sort of send messages, but has no logical relationship to sequential imperative OO languages such as Java.  Might just as well insist that a call be referred to as a "perform".)

Comment: (Note that that link is one (anonymous) person's opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Java SE javadocs, you'll see "this", "this instance", "this object", or "this <class>" used quite a bit.

[Object.equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

[`Collection.iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29)

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection.

Another decent example maybe [`Observer.update(Observable, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html#update%28java.util.Observable,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> This method is called whenever the observed object is changed. An
>   application calls an Observable object's notifyObservers method to
>   have all the object's observers notified of the change.

Note that the receiver is simply referred to by its classname.

Comment: This makes sense for javadoc that is referring to the current method. But what happens if it refers to another method and the object its called on?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That usually would be the "specified/given/argument <class>" if I understood you correctly, but I don't think that what the question was about.

Comment: The javadoc for `Object#equals` refers to `Object#equals`, but what if it referred to `Object#hashCode` called on some other object than `this` and the given argument? How would you call that object?

Comment: Instance methods are documented in the context of the instance itself. I'm not sure why they wouldn't be as you always need an instance to invoke them.

Comment: I'm going to hijack your answer for a second to explain what I meant. What other name would you give to `that instance`?

Answer (score 0):

In java it is often referred to as "this" object.

For instance:

> The contains() method simply checks if the input substring is present in **this** string.

It is consistent with the `this` keyword meaning in Java.

Comment: Unfortunately `this` doesn't have a context outside the object. This would be very hard to use if multiple objects are used in the discussion.